# If statement does not stop for loop

Tags: jquery, css

I have the code block below. It goes through a loop that changes the background position throughtout the loop. I am trying to stop the loop when I hover out. I am currently trying to do this using a boolean value `hoveredOut` which becomes true when the `OutHandler` of `hover()` is called. However, HoveredOut remains true and the loop always finishes. Right now it also always stays at the end and never resets back to 0.

So my questions:

- Am I approaching this correctly? Should I do something else than what I'm doing now with `hoveredOut`? It doesn't seem to be working now.
- Why is the loop not stopping when I am not hovering over `.headerGif`?
- Why is the loop not resetting when I hover over it again? It **does** reset when I comment out the whole `if(hoveredOut)` block but I need it to work with the hoveredOut check.

Hopefully you guys can see what the problem is.

```
var currentFrame = 0;
var running = false;
var hoveredOut = false;
var headerTimeout = 1000/24;

jQuery('.headerGif').hover(function () {
    var _this = this;
    if (!running) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 41; i++) {
            console.log ('HoveredOut value in loop:' + hoveredOut.toString());
            if (hoveredOut){
                hoveredOut = false;
                break;
            }
            (function (i) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                        running = true;
                        currentFrame = i;
                        offset = (i - 1) * 45;
                        jQuery(_this).css('background-position', '0 -' + offset + 'px');

                        console.log(offset);
                        console.log('Timeout: ' + i*100)
                        console.log('Current frame: ' + currentFrame);
                }, i*50);
            })(i);
         }
    }
    running = false;
}, function(){ // Hover out handler
    console.log ('Hovered out at frame ' + currentFrame);
    console.log ('HoveredOut value:' + hoveredOut.toString());
    hoveredOut = true;
    console.log ('HoveredOut value after change:' + hoveredOut.toString());
});
```

Comment: _Why is the loop not stopping when I am not hovering over .headerGif?_ Add `console.time("loop")` before and `console.timeEnd("loop")` after the loop and check you console. I guess the 40 iterations in the loop won't require more than 1-2 ms. Also check the order of the `console` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create such loop, you should use setInterval, and to stop it, use clearInterval.

code below and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/jpmpkarg/1/)

```
#container {
    background: gray;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
#container.hovering {
    background: green;
}
<div id="container"></div>

var ticker = 0;
var looper = false;
var tick_function = function() {
    ticker++;
    $("#container").text("ticker:"+ticker);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#container").hover(function() {
        $("#container").addClass("hovering");
        looper = setInterval(function() {
            tick_function();
        }, 500);
    }, function() {
        $("#container").removeClass("hovering");
        clearInterval(looper);
    });   
});
```

Comment: This is neat. Thank you!